# Functional Programming - Avoid mutable in match expression and changing int value

Tags: functional-programming, f#

I just started programming functionally. My current tiny project to start would be a basic pokemon battle.

Code first, explanation follows.

```
let choosePokemon () =
    let mutable pokemon = DemoData.schiggy
    let msg = Console.ReadLine()
    match msg with
    | "Schiggy" -> pokemon <- DemoData.schiggy
    | "Pikachu" -> pokemon <- DemoData.pikachu
    | "Kleinstein" -> pokemon <- DemoData.kleinstein
    | "Karpador" -> pokemon <- DemoData.karpador 
    pokemon
```

I am currently asking people to enter the name of a Pokemon and if it matches a predefined set (Schiggy, Pikachu, Kleinstein or Karpador) it gives them the respective Pokemon. Alternatively it gives them the default Pokemon.

I am currently creating it before matching it with "let mutable pokemon = DemoData.schiggy". I don't want that. I just want to assign it based on its name.

If I could go without that line I'd avoid making it mutable, which is something I don't want anyways.

Additional question further down the line: When Pokemon attack each other their hp will decrease.

How can I avoid using a mutable int when facing a changing int value?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `match` is expression and result of it can be assigned to variable: `let pokemon = match input with ... -> something | ... -> otherThing | _ -> defaultValue`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just return the result from the `match` - there's no need to declare a variable:

```
let choosePokemon () =
    let msg = Console.ReadLine()
    match msg with
    | "Schiggy" -> DemoData.schiggy
    | "Pikachu" -> DemoData.pikachu
    | "Kleinstein" -> DemoData.kleinstein
    | "Karpador" -> DemoData.karpador
```

The function is still impure, though, since it performs I/O (`Console.ReadLine`)...

It's also [partial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function), since it'll crash on any other input than the four strings being matched. Even misspellings and case mistakes are going to throw an exception.

A more robust pure function would be something like this:

```
let choosePokemon (input : string) =
    match input.Trim().ToUpperInvariant () with
    | "PIKACHU"    -> DemoData.pikachu
    | "KLEINSTEIN" -> DemoData.kleinstein
    | "KARPADOR"   -> DemoData.karpador
    | _            -> DemoData.schiggy
```

Contrary to the OP that performs I/O, this version is a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), since there's no non-deterministic behaviour. It's also total, since it returns `schiggy` as a default value.

To get the behaviour where you ask the user to input a value, compose the impure `Console.ReadLine` action with the pure `choosePokemon` function:

```
Console.ReadLine >> choosePokemon
```

Comment: I don't know how to PM on stackoverflow, but I wanted to thank you for your two VERY useful replies to my issues. I have finished my project thanks to your help :)