# Functional Programming - Avoid making my variable mutable when counting it down

Tags: functional-programming, f#

[Yesterday's thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70633865/functional-programming-avoid-mutable-in-match-expression-and-changing-int-valu?noredirect=1#comment124872140_70633865)

First let me thank you for yesterday's replies. I was able to continue.

My current issue is that I have been able to avoid making all variables mutable except for currentHP of a Pokemon.
Code of my battle first, explanation follows.

```
let angriffFighter(fighterPair:list<Domain.Pokemon>) =
    let dmg = hit fighterPair.[0] fighterPair.[1]
    fighterPair.[1].currentHP <- fighterPair.[1].currentHP-dmg
```

The function "hit" calculates dmg dealt and returns an int.
currentHP is the only remaining variable I can't seem to make immutable.
I need to reduce it in every battleround and I want it to reset to maxHP after the fight.

How would I tackle this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [copy-and-update expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/copy-and-update-record-expressions) to return a new record value with the changed fields:

```
let angriffFighter (fighterPair : list<Domain.Pokemon>) =
    let dmg = hit fighterPair.[0] fighterPair.[1]
    let new1 = { fighterPair.[1] with currentHP = fighterPair.[1].currentHP - dmg }
    [ fighterPair.[0]; new1 ]
```

But really, instead of passing a list around as a pair, it'd be much easier to just use a pair (a tuple):

```
let angriffFighter (x, y) =
    let dmg = hit x y
    x, { y with currentHP = y.currentHP - dmg }
```

This version takes a tuple as input and also returns a tuple of the same type. Simpler and safer, because with a tuple, you *know* that the first and the second element will be there. This is in contrast to a list, where indexing into a list (using `.[0]`, `.[1]`, etc.) is unsafe, because you don't know whether or not there's going to be an element at that index.

Comment: even better to use a Record type in this situation so you could get descriptive names for the left and right values

Comment: @EliemerVelez or a curried function: `let angriffFighter assailant target = ...`.  But of course you can also have descriptive names with a tuple argument: `let angriffFighter (assailant, target) = ...`.

Comment: @phoog The reason I made the function uncurried was that by taking the same type of input as it outputs, the function becomes an [endomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endomorphism), which endows it with [some attractive properties](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2017/11/13/endomorphism-monoid).